# Excel VBA count duplicates in Column B within same date in Column A

Tags: excel

I have an excel sheet with dates in Column A and Part Numbers in Column B. What I am trying to do is see how many parts are used on the same day more than once. The data I have is broken up into one month where there can be as many as 10,000 rows total for all days of the month. If I can use let's say 31 different colors, I would like to hi-lite the components for one day that have a duplicate or more than one.

Any sample code or help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Step 1: Create column that indicates duplicates exist

Add this formula to cell C1:

```
=COUNTIFS(A:A,A1,B:B,B1)
```

This will tell you how many rows have the same date and part number as row 1.  Copy down for all rows, which can be done by selecting the range C1 to the last cell in Column C and using keyboard shortcut CTRL+D to copy the formula from C1 into all other rows.  Now your entire column C tells you how many rows match the current row.

### Step 2: Apply conditional formatting

On the cells you wish to highlight, apply conditional formatting and select "Use a formula.." rule type.  For any cell in row 1, you'd use the formula:

```
=$C1>1
```

And choose your desired highlight formatting.  Then use the Format Painter to copy the conditional formatting to other rows or columns.

Comment: Miss Yu ... thanks for the help, this seems to work pretty well. How can I use the conditional formatting to hi-lite the cells with a different color for each day of the month?

Comment: I see why you were asking for a VBA solution now. The only way I know how to do that with built-in conditional formatting is to create a rule for each day of the month, such as `=AND($C1>1,DAY($A1)=1)`, `=AND($C1>1,DAY($A1)=2)`, et cetera. And give each conditional formatting rule a different colour. Thus there would be 31 rules to setup, which I realize is not great news. However, you'd only have to set it up once for a single cell, then use format painter for the rest of the worksheet. Not the best solution but a solution.

Comment: Thanks Miss Yu... I will try this out and see how it works. I don't mind having to put in all 31 rules. Thanks again for your help and time.